# JSON Data Not Showing In Plunker

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plunker

I am having trouble getting a JSON data document to appear/input into a HTML document on Plunker.

The current JS being used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Content Viewer Information
  function checkViewers() {
    //Base Variables
    var viewer = $('#viewed span.user');
    var totalViews = $('#viewed span.user').length;
    var shortenViews = $('#viewed span.user').length -1;

    if (totalViews === 0) {
        $('<span> 0 people have </span>').insertBefore($('#viewed span:last-child'));
    }
    if (totalViews === 2) {
        $('<span> and </span>').insertAfter(viewer.first());
    }
    if (totalViews >= 3) {
        viewer.slice(1).hide();
        $('<span> and </span>').insertAfter(viewer.first());
        $('<span class="user count"></span>').insertAfter(viewer.eq(2));
        $('.count').html(shortenViews + ' more people');
    }
  }

  checkViewers();

  //JSON Data
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
          responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

          var newViewers = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.profiles.length; i++) { 
              newViewers += '<span class="user">' + responseObject.profiles[i].firstName + ' ';
              newViewers += responseObject.profiles[i].lastName + '</span>';
          }

          //Update Page With New Content
          var viewerSection = $('#viewed');
          viewerSection.innerHTML = newViewers;

      }
  };

  xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
  xhr.send(null);
  console.log('JSON Fired');

});
```

The JSON Data should be inputted into the div `#viewed` with the viewers first and last name. I am not too familiar with Plunker, so I am not sure if I am going about something the wrong way within Plunker, or if a portion of the current code is causing the JSON Data to not be entered.

View the current [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r3vfz8GgDAwCXypUNZbU?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing jQuery and native dom methods then getting confused about what is what

This returns a jQuery object:

```
var viewerSection = $('#viewed');
```

This is applying a property to that jQuery object that won't update the DOM since it isn't being applied to a DOM node:

```
 viewerSection.innerHTML( newViewers);
```

to set the html using jQuery you need to use `html()` method:

```
 viewerSection.html( newViewers);
```

Or to set it using native method you need to do

```
var viewerSection = $('#viewed')[0]; /* returns the DOM node from jQuery object */
/* or */
var viewerSection = document.getElementById('viewed');
/* then */
viewerSection.innerHTML( newViewers);
```

I would suggest for DOM manipulation you pick either jQuery or native javascript and stick to using one or the other and don't mix them

**[Working Demo Using html()](http://plnkr.co/edit/1adbZk3AMIJTyIQY0tkW?p=preview)**

Comment: also note that since you are using jQuery the jQuery ajax API is easier to read than native `XMLHttpRequest` and has a simple callback system for success and errors